# HitTestResultCallback can't find UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf

i'm having some trouble trying to access a UserControl through HitTestResultCallback, i can find all the controls inside my UserControl, but what i wanna do is access UserControl Class, here is my code:

```
    public void DragStartInteraction()
    {
        VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(Application.Current.MainWindow, null, new HitTestResultCallback(myCallbackDragStartEvent), new PointHitTestParameters(_currentPoint));

        ...
    }

    private HitTestResultBehavior myCallbackDragStartEvent(HitTestResult result)
    {
        ...

        UserControl el = result.VisualHit as UserControl;

        ...

        return HitTestResultBehavior.Continue;
    }
```

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `HitTestResultCallback` will only be called for those visuals in a visual tree that actually have rendered content. For example in a Label control, the callback will only return the Border and the TextBlock that make up the Label, but not the Label control itself. The same is true for your UserControl.

You could either get the UserControl from the visuals passed to your HitTestResultCallback by calling [`VisualTreeHelper.GetParent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper.getparent.aspx).

Or, you also provide a [`HitTestFilterCallback`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.hittestfiltercallback.aspx). This callback gets every visual in the visual tree, and you could simply stop traversing the tree when a UserControl is passed in.

```
VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(
    Application.Current.MainWindow,
    obj =>
    {
        if (obj is UserControl)
        {
            // found it
            return HitTestFilterBehavior.Stop;
        }
        return HitTestFilterBehavior.Continue;
    },
    result => HitTestResultBehavior.Continue,
    new PointHitTestParameters(_currentPoint));
```

In case you want to get more than one hit UserControl, perhaps because they overlap at the point you're testing, or you are testing with a hit test geometry, you may continue filtering by returning `HitTestFilterBehavior.ContinueSkipChildren`.

Comment: I got in the same conclusion, unfortunately was not possible to filter using HitTestFilterCallback, I think that should be the same reason we can't find an UserControl on HitTestResultCallback, but thanks anyway.

Comment: I don't think it is "the same reason we can't find an UserControl on HitTestResultCallback". Those callbacks are definitely called for a different set of visuals. The solution shown above works at least with the simple UserControl with which I tested it.

Comment: my bad, it worked using filters. In my solution i didn't filter, just get the parent from the top most UIElement, it solved my problem, but it's good to know that it works filtering by user control, it's  a better way to do the same thing. thanks!